# How to get data from table on the website C#?

Tags: c#

I read many topics how to get data from the website etc., but i can't find a solution to my problem.

So, I am trying to get data from this table: 
http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81/dane-pomiarowe/automatyczne/stacja/118/parametry/461/dzienny/07.02.2017

but every method gives me only html code like this:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\"\n          content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n    <meta name=\"product\" content=\"GIOS WWW\">\n    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">\n    <meta name=\"author\" content=\"DAC SYSTEM\">\n                                        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/static/core.css?v3\" media=\"screen\" type=\"text/css\"/>\n            \n        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/static/browse.css?v3\"/>\n            <link rel=\"stylesheet\"\n          href=\"/static/../compass/stylesheets/styles/pl_OPO.css?v3\"/>\n    <title>WIOŚ Opole - Prezentacja pomiarów</title>\n    <script>\n    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\n                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),\n            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\n    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');\n\n    ga('create', 'UA-72664157-1', 'auto');\n    ga('send', 'pageview');\n\n</script>\n</head>\n<body class=\"metro browse base\">\n<header id=\"top-nav\" class=\"bg-dark\">\n    <div id=\"top-menu\" class=\"navigation-bar dark fixed-top center-content\" data-show=\"hover\">\n        <div class=\"navigation-bar-content container\">\n\n                <a href=\"/\" class=\"element\"><span class=\"icon-home\"></span> STRONA GŁÓWNA</a>\n    <span class=\"element-divider\"></span>\n\n            \n        <ul     class=\"element-menu\">\n                                                                        <li     class=\"first\">\n                        <a class=\"dropdown-toggle\" href=\"#\">Informacje</a>\n    \n                            \n        <ul     class=\"dropdown-menu dark menu_level_1\" data-role=\"dropdown\">\n                                                                        <li     class=\"first\">\n                        <a href=\"/ocena-jakosci-powietrza\" >Ocena jakości powietrza</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"/opis-monitorowanych-substancji\" >Opis monitorowanych substancji</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"/standardy-jakosci-powietrza\" >Standardy jakości powietrza</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"/indeks-jakosci-powietrza\" >Indeks jakości powietrza</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"/publikacje\" >Publikacje</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li     class=\"last\">\n                        <a href=\"/prognozy\" >Prognozy</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                \n        </ul>\n    \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a class=\"dropdown-toggle\" href=\"#\">Stacje pomiarowe</a>\n    \n                            \n        <ul     class=\"dropdown-menu dark menu_level_1\" data-role=\"dropdown\">\n                                                                        <li     class=\"first\">\n                        <a href=\"/stacje/aktywne\" >Stacje aktywne</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li     class=\"last\">\n                        <a href=\"/stacje/archiwalne\" >Stacje archiwalne</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                \n        </ul>\n    \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a class=\"dropdown-toggle\" href=\"#\">Dane pomiarowe</a>\n    \n                            \n        <ul     class=\"dropdown-menu dark menu_level_1\" data-role=\"dropdown\">\n                                                                        <li     class=\"first\">\n                        <a href=\"/dane-pomiarowe\" >Dane aktualne</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li     class=\"last\">\n                        <a href=\"/archiwalne-dane-pomiarowe\" >Dane archiwalne</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                \n        </ul>\n    \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"/komunikaty\" >Komunikaty</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li    >\n                        <a href=\"http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl/\"  target=\"_blank\" >WIOŚ Opole</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                                        <li     class=\"last\">\n                        <a href=\"/Regulamin_Portalu_Jakosci_Powietrza.pdf\" >Regulamin serwisu</a>\n    \n                            \n        </li>\n    \n                \n        </ul>\n    \n\n        </div>\n    </div>\n</header>\n\n<div class=\"a-big-header a-having-scrollable-background a-having-scroll-shadow \">\n      \n                    <div class=\"narrow-header center-content\">\n    <div class=\"a-logo\"></div>\n    <h1 class=\"title1\">OPOLSKIE</h1>\n    <h1 class=\"title2\">System monitoringu jakości powietrza</h1>\n          </div>\n</div>\n\n                <div id=\"address-bar\">\n                        <nav class=\"breadcrumbs  center-content sidebar-not-included\">\n                <ul>\n                                                                        <li class=\"\">\n                                <a href=\"/\">\n                                                                            <i class=\"icon-home\"></i>\n                                                                        Strona główna\n                                </a>\n                            </li>\n                                                                                                <li class=\"\">\n                                <a href=\"/dane-pomiarowe\">\n                                                                            <i class=\"icon-search\"></i>\n                                                                        Dane pomiarowe\n                                </a>\n                            </li>\n                                                                                                <li class=\"title\">pomiary automatyczne</li>\n                                                            </ul>\n                                            </nav>\n        </div>\n    \n    <div style=\"padding: 15px 0px\"\n         class=\"a-content-container  center-content sidebar-not-included\">\n                    <div class=\"a-content-tile\">\n            <div id=\"a-browse-data-filter-box\" class=\"fluent-menu\" data-role=\"fluentmenu\">\n        <ul class=\"tabs-holder\">\n            <li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#tab_home\">Filtrowanie wyników</a></li>\n                                </ul>\n\n        <div class=\"tabs-content\">\n            <div class=\"tab-panel\" id=\"tab_home\" style=\"display: block;\">\n                <div class=\"full-width\">\n                \n                    <div class=\"tab-panel-group\" style=\"width: 128px\">\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-content\">\n                            <div class=\"tab-content-segment\">\n\n                                <div class=\"a-date-range-chooser\">\n                                    <button class=\"fluent-button dropdown-toggle\">\n                                        <span class=\"icon-pie on-left\"></span>\n                                        <span class=\"button-label\">\n                                                                                      dzienny\n                                                                                  </span>\n                                    </button>\n                                    <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" data-role=\"dropdown\">\n                                                                              <li><a data-date-range=\"day\" href=\"#\">dzienny</a></li>\n                                                                                                                    <li><a data-date-range=\"month\" href=\"#\">miesięczny</a></li>\n                                                                              <li><a data-date-range=\"year\" href=\"#\">roczny</a></li>\n                                    </ul>\n                                </div>\n                                <div class=\"a-datepicker input-control text\"\n                                                                         >\n                                    <input type=\"text\">\n                                    <button class=\"btn-date\"></button>\n                                </div>\n                            </div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-caption\">Data i typ raportu</div>\n                    </div>\n\n                    <div class=\"tab-panel-group\" style=\"width: 300px\">\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-content\">\n                            <div class=\"tab-content-segment a-view-type-chooser\" style=\"width:62px\">\n                                <button class=\"fluent-big-button dropdown-toggle\">\n                                    <span class=\"icon-home\"></span>\n                                    <span class=\"button-label\">Rodzaj widoku</span>\n                                </button>\n                                <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" data-role=\"dropdown\">\n                                    <li class=\"checked active\"><a href=\"#\" data-view-type=\"station\">wiele\n                                            parametrów na jednej stacji</a></li>\n                                    <li><a href=\"#\" data-view-type=\"parameter\">jeden parametr na\n                                            wielu stacjach</a></li>\n                                </ul>\n                            </div>\n\n                            <div class=\"tab-content-segment\">\n                                <input class=\"a-s1\" type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:100%\">\n                            </div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-caption\">Sposób przeglądania</div>\n                    </div>\n\n                    <div class=\"tab-panel-group\">\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-content\">\n                            <div class=\"tab-content-segment\">\n                                <input class=\"a-s2\" style=\"width:100%\">\n                                \n                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \n                                                                                                </div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-caption\">Filtr</div>\n                    </div>\n\n                    <div class=\"tab-panel-group a-apply-box\">\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-content\">\n                            <div class=\"tab-content-segment\">\n                                <button class=\"a-apply-filter fluent-big-button\">\n                                    <span class=\"icon-filter\"></span>\n                                    <span class=\"button-label\">Zastosuj</span>\n                                </button>\n                                <div class=\"a-validation-info\" style=\"display:none\">\n                                </div>\n                            </div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"tab-group-caption\"></div>\n                    </div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \n                                                                                                                                                                                            </div>\n    </div>\n\n    <br>\n\n    <div id=\"a-data-browser\">\n        <h2>Użyj powyższego filtru, aby wyświetlić dane</h2>\n\n                  <div class=\"articleContainer\"\n               xmlns:schema=\"http://schema.org/\" typeof=\"schema:WebPageElement\"\n               about=\"/cms/content/pomiary/automatyczne\">\n            <h3 property=\"schema:headline\">UWAGA</h3>\n            <div property=\"schema:text\">Wszystkie wyniki pomiarowe przedstawiane są w czasie CET</div>\n          </div>\n          <br>\n        \n        <div class=\"accordion\" data-role=\"accordion\" data-closeany=\"false\">\n            <div class=\"a-charts accordion-frame\">\n                <a href=\"#\" class=\"heading active\">Wykres</a>\n\n                <div class=\"content\">\n                    <div id=\"chart-container\"></div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n            <div class=\"a-table accordion-frame\">\n                <a href=\"#\" class=\"heading active\">Tabela</a>\n\n                <div class=\"a-accordion-heading-right\">\n                    eksportuj do:\n                    <a href=\"#\" id=\"table-export-to-calc\">Excel</a>,\n                    <a href=\"#\" download=\"dane_pomiarowe.csv\" id=\"table-export-to-csv\">CSV</a>\n                </div>\n                <div class=\"content\">\n                    <div id=\"table-container\"></div>\n                    <div class=\"a-legend-box\">\n                        <h3>Legenda</h3>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color a-lv-exceeded\"></div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Przekroczenie poziomu dopuszczalnego.</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color a-tv-exceeded\"></div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Przekroczenie poziomu docelowego.</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color a-it-exceeded\"></div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Przekroczenie poziomu informowania.</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color a-at-exceeded\"></div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Przekroczenie poziomu alarmowego.</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n\n                        <br>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                            <div class=\"a-item-color\">1)</div>\n                            <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Brak wymaganego pokrycia danych.</div>\n                            <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color\">2)</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Wartość ośmiogodzinnej średniej kroczącej przypisanej do danej godziny stanowi średnią z ośmiu ostatnich ważnych wartości jednogodzinnych (przykładowo: dla godziny 1:00 do obliczeń brane są wartości pomiarów godzinnych z godzin 18:00-1:00, dla godziny 2:00 wartości z godzin 19:00-2:00 itd.).</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                        <div class=\"a-legend-item\">\n                          <div class=\"a-item-color\">3)</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-item-desc\">Zgodnie z Wytycznymi Komisji Europejskiej do decyzji 2011/850/UE przekroczenie normy jakości powietrza występuję wtedy, gdy wartość odpowiedniej statystyki (np. średniej rocznej) po zaokrągleniu do ilości miejsc znaczących z jaką podana jest norma przekracza wartość normowaną, np. poziom docelowy dla benzo(a)pirenu wynosi 1&nbsp;ng/m<sup>3</sup>, jeżeli stężenie średnioroczne benzo(a)pirenu na stanowisku pomiarowym wynosi 1,50&nbsp;ng/m<sup>3</sup> to zgodnie z ww. wytycznymi otrzymany wynik zaokrągla się do 2&nbsp;ng/m<sup>3</sup> (co jest przekroczeniem normy), jeżeli stężenie średnioroczne benzo(a)pirenu na stanowisku pomiarowym wynosi 1,48&nbsp;ng/m<sup>3</sup> to otrzymany wynik zaokrągla się do 1&nbsp;ng/m<sup>3</sup> (co nie jest przekroczeniem normy).</div>\n                          <div class=\"a-clear\"></div>\n                        </div>\n                                            </div>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n\n    <div class=\"a-browse-toolbar\">\n      <div class=\"a-toolbar-body\">\n                                                            <div class=\"a-label a-goto-btn\" data-goto=\"#a-data-browser .a-charts\">\n          <i class=\"icon-bars\"></i> wykres\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"a-label a-goto-btn\" data-goto=\"#a-data-browser .a-table\">\n          <i class=\"icon-stats\"></i> tabela\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"a-label a-hide-btn\" data-powertip=\"ukryj\">\n          <i class=\"icon-arrow-up-2\"></i>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"a-browse-toolbar2\">\n      <div class=\"a-toolbar-body\">\n        <div class=\"a-label a-show-btn\" data-powertip=\"pokaż pasek narzędzi\">\n          <i class=\"icon-arrow-down-2\"></i>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n\n    <div id=\"a-export2xls-help\">\n      <p>Do eksportu danych do arkusza kalkulacyjnego można wykorzystać schowek, w tym celu:</p>\n      <ol>\n        <li>Naciśnij kombinację klawiszy <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.</li>\n        <li>W arkuszu kalkulacyjnym użyj opcji <i>Wklej</i> lub naciśnij kombinację klawiszy <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>.</li>\n      </ol>\n    </div>\n\n    <script type=\"application/javascript\">\n        var date = 1486425600000;\n        var app = app || {};\n        app.config = app.config || {};\n        app.config.DataBrowser = {\n            dataUrl: '/dane-pomiarowe/pobierz',\n            stationState: 'active',\n                      configUrl: '/dane-pomiarowe/wczytaj-konfiguracje',\n                      useHistoryAPI: !!(window.history && history.pushState),\n            measType: 'auto',\n            data: { // null, jeśli selektor ma być domyślnie niewypełniony\n                viewType: 'station',\n                viewTypeEntityId: '118',\n                dateRange: 'day',\n                date: date + 3600000, // CET offset\n                channels: [461]\n            }\n        };\n    </script>\n\n    </div>\n        \n\n    </div>\n\n    <div class=\"a-footer\">\n        W serwisie wykorzystywane są pliki cookies w celu zapamiętania stanu elementów interfejsu.\n        <a id=\"acceptCookiesButton\" class=\"button small\" onclick=\"acceptCookies()\">Akceptuję</a>\n    </div>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n        function acceptCookies() {\n            Cookies.set('cookiesAccepted', 'yes');\n            $('.a-footer').slideUp();\n        }\n    </script>\n\n            <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/static/core.js?v3\"></script>\n        \n    \n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/static/browse.js?v3\"></script>\n    \n    <script src=\"/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData\"></script>\n    <script type=\"application/javascript\">\n        $(function () {\n            // separator w zależności od locale (jeśli występuje pl to użyj `;`)\n            var i18n = navigator.languages || (navigator.userLanguage && [navigator.userLanguage]) || (navigator.language && [navigator.language]) || [],\n                separator = (i18n.indexOf('pl') !== -1 ? ';' : ',');\n\n            //\n            /**\n             * Pozbywa się wrapperów wartości `\"` jeżeli występują.\n             * @param {string} csvValue\n             * @returns {string}\n             */\n            var trim = function(csvValue) {\n                return csvValue.replace(/^\"(.*)\"$/, '$1');\n            };\n            //\n            var csvBtn = $('#table-export-to-csv');\n            csvBtn.on('click', function (e) {\n                var data = $('#table-container > table').table2CSV({\n                    delivery: 'value',\n                    separator: separator,\n                });\n                var lines = data.split('\\n');\n\n                //begin: dostosowanie nagłówka\n                var headerLine = lines[0],\n                    headers = headerLine.split(separator),\n                    newHeaderLine = [headers[0]];\n\n                var len = (headers.length - 1) / 2;\n                for (var i = 1; i <= len; ++i) {\n                    var j = i + len;\n                    newHeaderLine.push('\"' + trim(headers[i]) + ' ' + trim(headers[j]) + '\"');\n                }\n                newHeaderLine = newHeaderLine.join(separator);\n                // usunięcie przypisów\n                newHeaderLine = newHeaderLine.replace(/\\d\\)/g, '');\n                lines.splice(0, 1, newHeaderLine);\n                //end: dostosowanie nagłówka\n\n                data = lines.join('\\n');\n\n                // usunięcie &nbsp;\n                data = data.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');\n\n                var link = this,\n                  d = new Date(),\n                  now = d.format('yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM-ss'),\n                  filename = 'dane-pomiarowe_' + now + '.csv';\n                FileSaver.saveAs(data, \"text/csv\", \"UTF-8\", filename, link);\n            });\n\n            var calcBtn = $('#table-export-to-calc');\n            var help = $('#a-export2xls-help');\n            calcBtn.on('click', function (e) {\n              e.preventDefault();\n              var table = $('#table-container > table');\n\n              $.Dialog({\n                overlay: true,\n                flat: true,\n                icon: '<i class=\"icon-file-excel\"></i>',\n                title: 'Eksportowanie danych do arkusza kalkulacyjnego',\n                content: help.html(),\n                padding: 10,\n                // dimm are set in css\n                onShow: function(_dialog){\n                  app.utils.selectContent(table.get(0));\n                },\n                onClose: function () {\n                  console.log('# A #');\n                }\n              });\n              // there is no close event in Dialog so one can bind to the close btn\n              $('.window.flat').find('button.btn-close').one('click', function() {\n                app.utils.clearSelection();\n              });\n\n            });\n\n            //\n            // toolbar\n            //\n            var isTransitionSupported = app.utils.supportCssProperty('transition');\n\n            var toolbar = $('.a-browse-toolbar');\n            var toolbar2 = $('.a-browse-toolbar2'); // przycisk \"pokaż\"\n\n            toolbar.find('.a-goto-btn').on('click', function(e) {\n              var selector = $(this).attr('data-goto');\n              app.scrollToEl(selector);\n            });\n\n            toolbar.find('.a-hide-btn').on('click', function(e) {\n              if (!toolbar.hasClass('a-hidden')) {\n                app.utils.cssTransition(toolbar, 'a-hidden', function() {\n                  toolbar2.fadeIn();\n                });\n                if (!isTransitionSupported) {\n                  toolbar2.fadeIn();\n                }\n              }\n            });\n            toolbar2.find('.a-show-btn').on('click', function(e) {\n              if (toolbar.hasClass('a-hidden')) {\n//                app.utils.cssTransition(toolbar, 'a-hidden', function() {\n//                  toolbar2.fadeOut();\n//                });\n                toolbar.toggleClass('a-hidden');\n                toolbar2.fadeOut(600);\n              }\n            });\n\n            toolbar.find('.a-shrink-table-btn').on('click', function(e) {\n              var cntr = $('#table-container');\n              cntr.children('table').addClass('a-shrinked-table');\n              cntr.doubleScroll('refresh');\n\n              $(this).hide();\n              toolbar.find('.a-expand-table-btn').show();\n            });\n            toolbar.find('.a-expand-table-btn').on('click', function(e) {\n              var cntr = $('#table-container');\n              cntr.children('table').removeClass('a-shrinked-table');\n              cntr.doubleScroll('refresh');\n\n              $(this).hide();\n              toolbar.find('.a-shrink-table-btn').show();\n            });\n        });\n    </script>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

where I can't find what I want to.

Comment: I know this is an dirty method but if you are not finding an better solution you could also use the String manipulation methods (Substring, IndexOf...)  and find the table values manually based on class and id names.

Comment: @Maciek - welcome to SO.  It's a good idea to post what you have tried already.  You might also want to read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the data for that table actually comes from a JSON service.

```
POST http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81/dane-pomiarowe/pobierz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 200
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
/User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Referer: http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81/dane-pomiarowe/automatyczne/stacja/118/parametry/461/dzienny/07.02.2017
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6
Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.3.1335419632.1486488241

query=%7B%22measType%22%3A%22Auto%22%2C%22viewType%22%3A%22Station%22%2C%22dateRange%22%3A%22Day%22%2C%22date%22%3A%2207.02.2017%22%2C%22viewTypeEntityId%22%3A%22118%22%2C%22channels%22%3A%5B461%5D%7D
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 17:25:49 GMT
Content-Length: 1470

{"success":true,"data":{"charts":[],"title":"Dane pomiarowe dla stacji Opole, ul. Koszyka w dniu 07.02.2017 r.","unitLabel":"&micro;g\/m<sup>3<\/sup>","series":[{"label":"Py\u0142 zawieszony PM10","measType":"auto","paramLabel":"Py\u0142 zawieszony PM10","paramId":"pm10","paramCode":"PM10","paramPostfix":"","aggType":"A1h","ord":7,"interval":3600,"count":24,"retroCount":2,"startTime":1486425600,"extStartTime":1486418400,"coverageRate":0.75,"isAvgValid":true,"thresholds":{"at":null,"it":null,"tv":null,"lv":null,"atDecimals":0,"itDecimals":0,"tvDecimals":0,"lvDecimals":0},"data":[["1486418400","57.3032"],["1486422000","55.3116"],["1486425600","59.175"],["1486429200","56.1021"],["1486432800","62.4833"],["1486436400","67.5783"],["1486440000","66.4557"],["1486443600","68.622"],["1486447200","64.8019"],["1486450800","65.7004"],["1486454400","61.8585"],["1486458000","67.2359"],["1486461600","57.9348"],["1486465200","48.9005"],["1486468800","51.9315"],["1486472400","54.7842"],["1486476000","52.2321"],["1486479600","53.8026"],["1486483200","47.3977"],["1486486800","46.0068"]],"avg":{"avg":false,"min":"46.0068","max":"68.622"},"thresholdsForAvg":{"avg":{"at":300,"it":200,"tv":null,"lv":50,"atDecimals":0,"itDecimals":0,"tvDecimals":0,"lvDecimals":0},"min":null,"max":null},"decimals":0,"unit":"ug\/m3","unitLabel":"&micro;g\/m<sup>3<\/sup>","scaleMin":null,"scaleMax":null,"chartTooltipContent":"%y.# %ly o godz. %x"}],"dateFormat":"H:00","viewType":"station"}}
```

If you decode the `query` parameter, it is actually JSON as well:

```
{"measType":"Auto","viewType":"Station","dateRange":"Day","date":"07.02.2017","viewTypeEntityId":"118","channels":[461]}
```

So, at a high level, you could make a `POST` to this JSON and parse the results.  A good way to upload the data is to use [`WebClient.UploadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use JSON.Net to parse the result using, [`JToken.Parse`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonAny.htm) for example, and you can access the elements you are looking for.

```
string url = "http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81/dane-pomiarowe/pobierz";
string data = "query=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("{\"measType\":\"Auto\",\"viewType\":\"Station\",\"dateRange\":\"Day\",\"date\":\"07.02.2017\",\"viewTypeEntityId\":\"118\",\"channels\":[461]}");

System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
string response = wc.UploadString(url, data);

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(response);

DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
foreach (var entry in jsonResponse["data"]["series"][0]["data"])
{
    Response.Write("UTC Time: " + epoch.AddSeconds((int)entry[0]) + ", Value: " + entry[1] + "<br>");
}
```

Here is the result:

```
UTC Time: 2/6/2017 10:00:00 PM, Value: 57.3032
UTC Time: 2/6/2017 11:00:00 PM, Value: 55.3116
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 12:00:00 AM, Value: 59.175
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 1:00:00 AM, Value: 56.1021
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 2:00:00 AM, Value: 62.4833
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 3:00:00 AM, Value: 67.5783
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 4:00:00 AM, Value: 66.4557
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 5:00:00 AM, Value: 68.622
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 6:00:00 AM, Value: 64.8019
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 7:00:00 AM, Value: 65.7004
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 8:00:00 AM, Value: 61.8585
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 9:00:00 AM, Value: 67.2359
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 10:00:00 AM, Value: 57.9348
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 11:00:00 AM, Value: 48.9005
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 12:00:00 PM, Value: 51.9315
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 1:00:00 PM, Value: 54.7842
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 2:00:00 PM, Value: 52.2321
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 3:00:00 PM, Value: 53.8026
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 4:00:00 PM, Value: 47.3977
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 5:00:00 PM, Value: 46.0068
UTC Time: 2/7/2017 6:00:00 PM, Value: 45.5689
```

Comment: Yup, you found those elements (last line in your 1st <code>), but I think that I am not so <educated?> to do this without some example. I you could paste sth it would be so great.
However, thank you

Comment: @Maciek - I added some more sample code.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It worked and I think that I understand this a little bit. Thank you so much !
<can't +1>

Comment: Can you tell me where did you find:
http://www.opole.pios.gov.pl:81/dane-pomiarowe/pobierz
link to send the query, because I have few more sites to collect those informations?

Comment: I used Fiddler - http://www.telerik.com/fiddler - when you have the program running you can see all browser requests when loading a page.  There is a little bit of hunting and pecking, but once you get used to it you can pretty easily find these types of things.